# Is Container interface defined in jersey-server library is a Jakarta EE Container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have been trying to implement a JAX-RS based jersey server. I came across an interface ‘Container’ which can be managed using ‘ApplicationHandler’ class. My question is if this interface is directly related to the general definition of Container in Jakarta specification?

Comment: Can you refer to `Container in Jakarta specification`?